# Indicial notation help on square of dot product

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I prove the following using Index notation.

$$(A \cdot B)^2 + (A \times B) \cdot (A \times B) = |A|^2 |B|^2$$

$$A \cdot B = A_i B_i,  $$

so is the square $$A^2_i B^2_i$$?

and $$(A \times B) \cdot (C \times D) = A_iC_iB_jD_j - A_iD_iB_jC_j $$

so is $$ (A \times B) \cdot (A \times B) = 0 $$?

So will this be the solution? $$A^2_i B^2_i = |A|^2|B|^2$$

Comment: $$(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B})\cdot(\mathbf{A}\times\mathbf{B}) = 0$$ if and only if one of the following obtains:$$\mathbf{A}  = \mathbf{0},$$
$$\mathbf{B}  = \mathbf{0},\ \mathrm{or}$$
$$\mathbf{A}\ \mathrm{is\ parallel\ to\ }\mathbf{B}.$$

Also, $$\mathbf{A}\cdot\mathbf{B} = |\mathbf{A}||\mathbf{B}|$$ under the exact same conditions.

Comment: @vmark99 Something to help you catch yourself before running too far with a mistake: $A_i^2B_i^2=A_iA_iB_iB_i$ doesn't work.  You can only have two of the same index in any given term.  If you ever have an expression with more than two, you've made a mistake.

Comment: $A_iB_i$ is the shortened notation for the sum of product of same indexed members of the two vectors, and the square of a sum *isn't* the sum of squares.  Think of the notation as having an invisible $\sum_i$ preceding the terms.$$(\color{silver}{\sum_i}A_iB_i)^2 = \color{silver}{\sum_i\sum_j}A_iB_iA_jB_j$$

Comment: Ah okay got it!  Now it makes sense. Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward, really.  Identities to remember:

1. $X\cdot Y = X_iY_i$
2. $[X\times Y]_i = \epsilon_{ijk}X_jY_k$
3. $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{ilm} = \delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl}$
4. $\|X\|^2 = X\cdot X = X_iX_i$

Then, starting from the LHS, we get

$$\begin{align}(A\cdot B)^2 + \|A\times B\|^2 &= A_iB_iA_jB_j + \epsilon_{ijk}A_jB_k\epsilon_{ilm}A_lB_m \\ &= A_iB_iA_jB_j + (\delta_{jl}\delta_{km}-\delta_{jm}\delta_{kl})A_jB_kA_lB_m \\ &= \require{cancel}\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{A_iB_iA_jB_j}}} + A_jA_jB_mB_m-\color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{A_jB_jB_kA_k}}} \\ &= (A\cdot A)(B\cdot B) \\ &= \|A\|^2\|B\|^2 \ \ \ \ \square\end{align}$$

Note that this is actually quite simple to prove without index notation:

$$\begin{align}(A\cdot B)^2 + \|A\times B\|^2 &= \|A\|^2\|B\|^2\cos^2(\theta) + \|A\|^2\|B\|^2\sin^2(\theta) \\ &= \|A\|^2\|B\|^2\left(\cos^2(\theta)+\sin^2(\theta)\right) \\ &= \|A\|^2\|B\|^2\end{align}$$